# How can I use arrayformula so I got the cell value that used last time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a table of content on google sheet where word list on **column B** and image name on **column C**. On column C image name is not given for every cell. Now I need to use **ARRAYFORMULA** on **Cell D1** where it will give the output (Word name and Image Name) on **Column D** if Row of **Column A** is not empty. If you look at the attached screenshot, for some Word there is no image name given on **column C**. In this case I need the image name that used last time.
**`For example:`** On **Row 17** for **WORD 4** there is no image name given. So, in this case the image name will be **Image 2** from **cell C12** that used previously for **WORD 3**. I tried it in many different ways but never able to do it with ARRAYFORMULA. The only solution I am using right now is using formula for every row which is not a good solution. I need to do it with ARRAYFORMULA. I don't want to do it with google script.

**➡** [Spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HOaUiI8Ubwm0yzFY-A2kNuTTNX7_OMCZBTmqggFgGZI/edit?usp=sharing) (Please check **Tab 1**)

**➡** [Please check the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iY0h.png)

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet that contains the same data shown in your attached image. Be sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." This will be the easiest way to receive help.

Comment: @ErikTyler Thank you for your Response . I added the spreadsheet link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in D1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header";IF(A2:A="",,B2:B&" : "&VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER({ROW(A2:A),C2:C},C2:C<>""),2,TRUE))})`

This one array formula creates a header and then fills the entire column with results.

You can change "Header" to whatever you like.

`IF(A2:A="",,` just leaves D2:D null if nothing is in that row of Col A.

Otherwise, whatever is in `B2:B` is concatenated with a space-colon-space and then a `VLOOKUP` of all rows within a `FILTER`ed virtual array that contains only rows and Col-C data where Col C is not blank. Because `TRUE` is chosen as the final parameter, all rows will "look backward" to the last row where Col C *did* contain data and return that data as the final piece to be concatenated.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Would you now take a moment and mark this post as "Best Answer"? It will indicate at a glance from the home page listings that this issue has been fully solved; and it will help future site visitors more easily find this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(isnumber(SEARCH("WORD",B2,1)),join(" : ",B2, indirect(ARRAYFORMULA(address(IFNA(match(2,1/($C$2:$C2<>"")))+1,COLUMN(C2))))),"")
```

past this formula in D1 cell and drag it ...

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid the drag. I already solved it with drag. But thank you so much for your time. I appreciate It.